# Inner products in Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization

Tags: integration, orthogonal-polynomials, gram-schmidt, quadrature

I am using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to create orthogonal polynomials with respect to an arbitrary weight function in a n-dimensional space (not always orthotope).

$P_i(\mathbf{x})=B_i(\mathbf{x})-\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\frac{\left\langle B_i,P_j\right\rangle}{\left\langle P_j,P_j\right\rangle}P_j(\mathbf{x})$

Where $P_i$ is the i-th polynomial of my orthogonal basis and $\{B_i\}$ is an initial (and known) set of polynomials. My problem is that I have an inner product $\langle\cdot\rangle$ i.e. an integral in nD to perform numerically, the use of a quadrature rule requiters an orthogonal polynomial basis that I don't have yet since I am constructing it.

How do people generally perform this integral ? I was thinking about a Monte-Carlo integration but I may generate a lot of errors, especially in unbounded integration domains.

Comment: They are elementary when you do not have an arbitrary weight function, what I have to integrate here is a polynomial times a weight function that is not a polynomial, this is the definition of my inner product. Quadrature rules exist for 1D bounded and unbounded domains, for example the Gauss-Hermite quadrature. Unfortunately I cannot use them here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the weight functions. What do they look like.

Comment: It is the probability density of a random variable, but not always one of the conventional ones, the weight function may also have no closed-form.

Comment: Can't you perform a change of variable to get a bounded interval ?

Comment: Indeed I can use the polynomial chaos algorithm I am working on to map my unbounded variables into a bounded space that will suit better to a (quasi-)Monte Carlo integration.